# Chamar o certificado digital do navegador

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Como faço para chamar o certificado digital do navegador para que o meu webapp em asp.net mvc possa assinar um xml e depois devolver ao usuario?

Vi recursos que utiliza o java ou outro applet, mas não gostaria de usar qualquer pluging. E sim em usar recursos mais nativos possíveis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá Joandreiy Cordeiro.

Segue alguns endereços onde poderá conter as resposta que está procurando, inclusive a explicação do funcionamento da Certificação.

1)  https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee923720.aspx
2)  http://www.devmedia.com.br/autenticacao-de-usuarios-com-certificados-digitais-parte-i/9495
3)  http://www.devmedia.com.br/autenticacao-de-usuarios-com-certificados-digitais-parte-ii/9496